# Need to create a PIPE for an array of elements in angular2

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular, angular2-pipe

Am trying to create a angular 2 pipe for the array of elements so that it filters the only that elements based on the selected false,

my array

```
this.states =  [ {name: 'John', selected: false, value: 1}, {name: 'Bill', selected: false, value: 2},
    {name: 'Smith', selected: false, value: 3}, {name: 'Alex', selected: false, value: 4},
    {name: 'Martin', selected: false, value: 5}, {name: 'James', selectes: false, value: 6}];
```

I need to filter the value which is of selected false,

My Pipe Code

```
import {Injectable,Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe ({
name : 'restrictValues'
})
@Injectable()
export class restrictValues implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.id.indexOf(args[1]) !== true);
    }
}
```

My HTML Implementation

```
  <select ngControl="select_state" (change)="statechange()" #select_state="ngForm" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
    <option *ngFor="#statez of states | restrictValues : false" value="{{statez.value}}">
        {{statez.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

The pipes in not working as expected please correct me if any thing is wrong in the code

Answer (score 2):

```
@Pipe({
    name:'restrictValues'
})
@Injectable()
export class restrictValues implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.selected === false);
    }
}
```

Notice how your code sample isn't actually looking at the `selected` property of your object - it's selecting `id`.

Comment: am trying to remove the selected options from selected box if its already selected in another select box using angular 2 do you have any idea on that

Answer (score 2):

You might need to make the pipe impure

```
@Pipe ({
  name : 'restrictValues',
  pure: false
})
```

otherwise it won't be called when items are added/removed/modified in `states`.

This causes the pipe to be executed at each change detection cycle. You might consider using an observable that actively notifies about changes.

Also in newer Angular2 version (since ~RC.1) the optional parameters aren't passed as an array anymore

```
transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
```

should be

```
transform(items: any[], param1?:any, param2?:any): any {
```

depending on how many parameters you want to support

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable,Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe ({
name : 'restrictValues'
})
@Injectable()
export class restrictValues implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => !item.selected);
    }
}
```